# Is it legal for websites to keep Logs of a persons billing information after it's deleted from an account?

Tags: united-states

For example, if I delete my billing info from my Microsoft account, is it gone forever? And if they keep it, is that legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s legal.

Every privacy law everywhere allows keeping data for legally mandated purposes - billing records are necessary for, among other things, tax laws, so they can be kept.